# Maven compilation failure due to mojo compiler

Tags: java, maven, mojo

I've downloaded **java 1.8** and **maven 3.8.2** but whenever I run my app I keep getting this:

```
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ project >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1815 source files to {path}/target/classes

The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:625)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBinary(Attr.java:3056)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBinary.accept(JCTree.java:1785)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.550 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-14T17:36:05+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/767M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project generic: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

There's something with the mojo compilation.....
Please help thank you!

**UPDATE:**
I tried updating my compiler from maven-compiler-plugin:3.:compile to maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile but I'm still getting the same error

> 

```
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ project >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1815 source files to {path}/target/classes

The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:625)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBinary(Attr.java:3056)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBinary.accept(JCTree.java:1785)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.470 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-14T18:28:00+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project generic: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project generic: Compilation failure
An unknown compilation problem occurred

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Use a more recent version of maven-compiler-plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: tried updating it but i still get the same error

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project generic: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred @khmarbaise

Comment: Ok...first step..second step which code produces the problem?

Comment: whenever i try to **mvn clean install** or run tomcat7 @khmarbaise

Comment: Please show the code which produces the compile error...

Comment: ive attached the compile error above

Comment: This must be a JDK bug. It looks a bit like https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4776875